# How to draw a line down the center of a container, vertically and horizontally?

Tags: flutter

I want to mark the exact center of the screen. How would I draw two lines, one down the center vertically, and one centered horizontally?

Comment: use `CustomPaint` widget

Comment: can you show a image of the result you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Mukul Literally just a 1px wide line straight down the middle and across the middle, so they intersect at the exact center of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code which uses custom painter, you can change the color of line by changing the color property of Paint class in AKCustomPainter class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() => runApp(Demo());

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SnackBar Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Demo'),
        ),
        body: Container(
              child: CustomPaint(
                size: Size(800,500), //You can Replace this with your desired WIDTH and HEIGHT
                painter: AKCustomPainter(),
)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class AKCustomPainter extends CustomPainter{
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    
    
  // Vertical line
  Paint paint_0 = new Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.34;
     
         
    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(size.width*0.50,0);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width*0.50,size.height);

    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0);
  
  
  // Horizontal line
  Paint paint_1 = new Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.34;
     
         
    Path path_1 = Path();
    path_1.moveTo(0,size.height*0.50);
    path_1.lineTo(size.width,size.height*0.50);

    canvas.drawPath(path_1, paint_1);
  
    
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

simplest solution could be to just wrap your screen scaffold into stack widget:

```
Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: [
    Scaffold(body: Container(color: Colors.white)),
    Align(
      child:
          Container(color: Colors.red, width: 1, height: double.infinity),
    ),
    Align(
      child:
          Container(color: Colors.red, width: double.infinity, height: 1),
    )
  ]),
```